# "policy" E667: Fsync failed when using vim to edit pcie_aspm/parameters/policy

Tags: vim, redhat

When I try edit the pcie_aspm/parameters/policy file as root, I receive the below error in my vim file editor? How do I edit this file?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error (E667: Fsync failed) and it was caused by a lack of disk space.

To solve this problem, I had to remove some other files to free some disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Errors :
while saving and quitting
"File1" E667: Fsync failed

while quitting
"File2" E667: Fsync failed
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!

Reason :
This problem is caused when there is Space issue.

Troubleshooting:
Please check the file system space.

user@server:~/home> df -h .
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2  297G  204G   94G  69% /home/

Check Inode use

user@server:~/home> df -hi .
Filesystem                Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2    15M  518K   15M    4% /home/

Check user's quota on the filesystem

> > Ask ur admin

Now remove or move large file to other location.

This will fix above error.